# Optimize Loading data in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` that uses an `ArrayAdapter` to load data. The loading method of records in the `ListView` is started with my application and read a file in a directory.

I was thinking of keeping these records in a database so that when it starts again and do not read the directory if not the database, but I would like your suggestions, to make loading faster records after the first load.

Comment: Try to rephrase your question because it is quite hard to understand.

Comment: Perror sorry, I'm still learning the English, I will try to formulate better the question

Comment: I wasn't criticizing. It was just an advice on how to improve your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

What kind of information do you need to read and what's your app going to be used for? If it is a task the user knows he/she has to wait, you could deploy any of the described loading methods, load everything on memory and construct the ListView later.

Could you describe the "changes" the list will have?

Comment: What I have read are files of any type and will show on the list, my question basically was in the amount of files that may have the directory, can be great.
With respect to operations, would only have the basic copy, move and delete.

thanks

Comment: You could implement a CursorLoader that populates the ListView with a limited amount of records from DB. When the user scrolls to the ListView's last record you could restart the loader to get the following records. By implementing a CursorLoader, the Main Activity that holds the ListView could automatically update when operations are executed and datasets are managed automatically thanks to the LoaderManager.

Comment: Ok Andres I will to review the topics.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how large and how process intensive parsing your files is. You'll need to test to see if it's actually faster to query a database rather than just parsing/caching your file data. Unless your data set is relatively small and not very process intensive, you'll most likely find that querying a db is faster. Just MAKE SURE you're not processing your data - either by reading a file or querying a db on the UI thread!

Here's the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) on how to make sure that doesn't happen.

Also, CommonsWare (sp?) has a great loader library out to work with your sqlite db if that's the way you choose to go. Check out the [other libs](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) there as well.